# Universal property characterizing $\Bbb R$

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples

Is it possible to characterize the field of real numbers in a natural way with the language of category theory?

For example, $\Bbb Q$ is the initial object in the category of ordered fields and $\Bbb Z$ is the initial object in **Ring**. I'm hoping for something similar with $\Bbb R$.

**EDIT:** Of course any object in the (quite boring) category of complete ordered fields will do, but completeness is a very strong property (in particular it's second-order logic), so I was hoping that one can express this aspect of the real numbers by only using arrows, and that the category with which you deal is given by simple properties, favourably those which can be stated in first-order language.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is the initial object of the category of complete ordered fields.

Comment: It's also probably the only object in that category, depending on how you define "complete".

Comment: A very nice result is explained in Theo's answer [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76134/topological-characterisation-of-the-real-line); this is not what you want, but it is sufficiently pretty to deserve a link :-)

Comment: Do you want a universal property within the category of fields? Or are ordered fields also OK?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Ordered fields are OK.

Comment: @Hew: More precisely, the category of complete ordered fields is equivalent (but not isomorphic!) to the terminal category (with only one object, and only its identity). In light of that I find Mariano's comment a bit misleading (although correct, of course), because it somehow suggests that there are essentially more complete ordered fields. But $\mathbb{R}$ is the only one, up to unique(!) isomorphism.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, I did not suggest any such thing: in fact, my comment was essentially a joke.

Comment: Then I hope that everyone understands this as a joke ;)

Answer (score 7):

This question leads directly to the notion of a [real closed field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field). These are ordered fields which "believe that they are $\mathbb{R}$". More precisely, they satisfy the same first order sentences as $\mathbb{R}$. It turns out that already two sentence schemes suffice: Every positive element is a square, and every polynomial of odd degree has a root. There are several other interesting characterizations, which can be found in the Wikipedia article. See also the references given there.

Every ordered field has a real closed algebraic extension, the so called real closure. This gives lots of examples of real closed fields, not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. For example, the real closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R} \cap \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, i.e. the field of real algebraic numbers.

This strongly suggests that there isn't any first-order universal property of $\mathbb{R}$ within the category of ordered fields, since solutions for universal problems are always isomorphic.

At least we can observe the following: If $K$ is an ordered field, then there is at most one homomorphism of fields $\mathbb{R} \to K$. For a proof, let $f : \mathbb{R} \to K$ be such a homomorphism. Then it has to be monotonic: If $x \leq y$, then $y-x$ is a square, hence also $f(y-x)=f(y)-f(x)$ is a square, which implies $f(x) \leq f(y)$. When $K$ is equipped with the order topology, then $f$ becomes continuous. Since $f|_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is unique and $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $f$ is unique.

Observe that $f$ exists if and only if all rational Cauchy sequences have a limit in $K$.

Comment: «Every polynomial of odd degree has a root» is not a 1st order sentence, no?

Comment: @Mariano: it's a first-order axiom schema.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, hm, not really: one needs, essentially, one axiom per degree (you can lump  a few in each axiom, but you still need infinitely many of them), because you cannot put them in a schema, for they are too different syntactically (at least, not in a schema like that of Replacement or the one one uses for induction in first order PA) Notice that my comment is an objection to Martin's «one can do this with two sentences»; of course, one can do what he wants with countably many sentences.

Comment: This is similar to the fact that one cannot say that a field is of characteristic zero with finitely many first order sentences.

Comment: I have written "two sentence schemes".

Comment: The last part doesn't seem right: that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$ does not follow from $f$ being strictly increasing (if $K$ is not archimedean and $\varepsilon \in K^{>0}$ is infinitesimal, then $f^{-1}(]q-\varepsilon;q+\varepsilon[) = \{q\} \subset \mathbb{Q}$ is not open), and it would not make it unique. If $K$ is a ultrapower of the field of real algebraic numbers $\mathbb{A}$, then it has several maximal archimedean subfields which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$: one containing the class of $((1 + \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1})$ and one containing that of $((1 + \frac{1}{n^2+1})^{n^2+1})$.